# Returning Bad Request (HTTP 400) errors on incorrect data types WCF Web API

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Web API. Some endpoints accept DataContracts which obviously contain different properties and datatypes. If a request contains a property with an incorrect data type (i.e. A string in an integer property) the value comes through as null after being serialized. Is there a simple way to instead, throw back a HTTP 400 Bad Request response (and possibly the offending property).

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the method's code

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways :

```
if(param == null){
    throw new HttpException(400, "Bad Request, param is invalid");
    //or 
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad Request, param is invalid");
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of something a bit more generic that detects that the serialization has failed. Perhaps even a configuration setting if there is one for this.

Comment: @Shorttylad Was not your question about how to generate an Error 400?

Comment: No, perhaps the wording could have been better.. I basically need to know how to throw 400 error automatically whenever the .NET core code doesn't serialize a value correctly - by default the value just comes through as null.